# Python: trailing comma after a catch-all argument

Tags: python, syntax

I am baffled by the trailing comma in a function parameter list:

```py
def f( *args, ): pass
```

earns me a `SyntaxError` exception. In python 3, even this:

```py
def f( *, arg = 1, ): pass
```

raises a syntax error exception. Both point to the closed parenthesis.

Removing the trailing comma, everything is quiet.
I am scratching my head on https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions but it is somehow beyond me (and possibly also wrong... at least, in my browser's rendering I can't pair the last closing parenthesis in the `parameter_list` definition).
Am I doing something wrong?
I am the

```py
def f(*,
      a: "doc A" = 1,
      b: "doc B" = 2,
      c: "doc C" = 3,
      d: "doc D" = 4,
      # ... and maybe more,
     )
```

type of person, and this issue kind-of annoys me (maybe that is the wrong part, and I should become the `, a: "doc A" = 1` type of person - but it looks weird to me).

Using python as distributed in Gentoo ebuilds dev-lang/python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 (from http://www.python.org).

Comment: Why do want a comma at the end, when you have no more functional arguments?

Comment: @be_good_do_good: the trailing comma makes it easier to rearrange the arguments or add new ones. It's about editing convenience and ease of maintenance. In terms of functionality there is, of course, no difference.

Comment: @be_good_do_good: For consistency and smaller version diffs when adding/removing/re-ordering lines. They are encouraged by many style guides, including PEP8 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Support for trailing commas following a catch-all argument [was added in python 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue9232).

It is not supported in 3.5 which explains your `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score -2):

Trailing commas in parameter lists are treated as multiple values separated by commas.

```
a = (4)
type (a)

>> output: int


a = (4,)
type (a)

>> output: tuple
```

So if the parameters of a function have a trailing comma, python thinks that there should be a value but there isn't, so it raises a syntax error.

Trailing commas in lists, on the other hand, are fine.

```
list1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, ]

>> totally fine
```

Comment: Well, `del f( a, ): pass` is also totally fine.

Comment: The OP is asking about commas in function _definitions_, not in calling sequences.